# Mouse considered as a keyboard by device manager

Tags: keyboard, mouse, sleep, windows-11

All mice in the device manager (see below) have been configured not to wake up my computer by unticking the box.

[image]

When I run `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`, only keyboards appear
[image]

When I put my laptop to sleep I can still wake it up with my mouse ?!

When I run `powercfg /lastwake`, I get the following:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: USB\VID_046D&PID_C53A\7&2aaa6b14&0&4
    Friendly Name:
    Description: USB Composite Device
    Manufacturer: (Standard USB Host Controller)
```

*First question:* **How can I identify the thing that is waking my computer up more precisely without deactivating random stuff in the device manager (it takes a lot of trial and error!)?**

When I go to the event viewer, the log is the following:
[image]

But I'm quite the newbie when it comes to technology so I don't really understand much of it. *Second question*: **Would this help identifying the culprit?**

I disabled all the keyboards, and now I cannot wake up my laptop with my mouse. I finally identified the "keyboard" that was actually my mouse. *Third question*: **How do I fix the fact that my computer thinks my mouse (`G703 lightspeed Logitech`) is, in fact, not a keyboard?**

I'm using `Windows 11 Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621`.

Comment: Is it a wireless mouse? Can you show what the mouse looks like in Device Manager's "View by Connection" mode?

Comment: It is a wireless mouse yes.

Comment: I cannot find the mouse in Device Manager's "View by Connection" mode

Comment: This is what is shown in this menu: https://i.imgur.com/m9mobda.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is guide how to find out proper device and disable wake function for it:
https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-find-out-what-woke-your-windows-10-pc-from-sleep

UPD: "USB Composite Device" means that your device have [multiple usb interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-common-class-generic-parent-driver) and consist of multiple "subdevices". You can see them in "View->Devices by connection" mode of Device Manager.

Also because your mouse is a HID device and may contain [multiple top-level collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/top-level-collections) in its HID Report Descriptor Windows can create another set of subdevices in device tree for each HID top-level collection. This is usual for many mouses with "extended" or "reprogrammable" buttons - so for some actions it may generate "keyboard key" (for example "next track" or "volume up") events etc.

Here is what Windows showing for my Logitech Unifying Receiver plus Keyboard and Mouse:

[image: USB Composite Device]

So in fact I have one hardware USB device connected to my PC but Windows recognizes it as several devices.

To find your mouse in "Devices by connection" mode just click on it in another mode to make it focused and then switch to the "Devices by connection" mode. It should open corresponding subtree automagically.

Comment: If only you read my post, I have done everything in that guide and I did solve my problem. I'm just wondering why my mouse is considered to be a keyboard in the device manager.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I have updated my answer.